# Number of edges in "half" a hypercube?

Tags: geometry

So it is easy to find number of edges given a half-square and half-cube by simply drawing, or just by intuition. We have two cases in both of these.

The square has 4 line of symmetry. If we define half-square by a line going through the edges, we can say half-square has **3** edges. If we define it by  a line going through the sides, we can say half-square has **2** edges (or, well, 4). For a half-cube by the same logic we either have **6** or **4** (or 8).

The question is how do you generalize it to an n-cube? How do you even find how many different cases are you looking for? And even if you manage that, how can you determine how many edges does a half-n-cube has?

Comment: what is a half-hypercube?

Comment: It is what we get if we consider only one side of a hyperplae of symmetry,I guess. I'd look at it the same way as the half-square is either a right triangle (if the symmetry line we choose goes through the edges) or a rectangle (if the symmetry line we choose goes through the sides)

Comment: a half-square is a rectangle?

Comment: Like this: http://www.loisterms.com/onehalf.jpg . The other choice is this: https://debgeyer.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/halfsquaretriangle31.jpg . I'd take them both as half of a square